# How to print current date and some text as well as some values from another cell?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

Hello guys I want a excel query that shows me below outout.

```
Timesheet : 28 August, 2018 - 03hr:05min
```

- First value is text (Timesheet :).
- Second value is current date with formatting as (`DD MMMM, YYYY`)
- and last value get from another cell.

I have tried but its not working for me:

```
='Timesheet : '&today()&' - '&C31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try,

```
="Timesheet : "&text(today(), "dd mmmm, yyyy")&" - "&C31
'alternate
="Timesheet : "&text(today(), "dd mmmm, yyyy - ")&text(C31, "hh\h\r:mm\m\i\n")
```

Comment: Thank You so much, Its working for me `="Timesheet : "&text(today(), "dd mmmm, yyyy")&" - "&C31`